# PHP: How to express IF this variable contains something then do something

Tags: php

The following code works with an xml script to check if a given email is in a given contact list and then it prints the results. But for some reasons is giving a SUCCESS all the time, even when the email is not found on that given contaact list.
BUT when it is supposed to find the email on a given contact list it DOES print the result.

SO what i want to do is say "IF result is not empty then send an email to X"

```
$ch = curl_init('http://clientes.cupon0km.com/xml.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = @curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false) { 
   echo "Error performing request";
}
else {
$xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo 'status is ', $xml_doc->status, '<br/>';
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS') {
print_r($result);
} else {
echo 'Error is ', $xml_doc->errormessage, '<br/>';
}
}
```

Basically what i dont know what to do is on the second if how to say IF $result contains something (meaning it doesnt return as empty) then send an email to X??

Answer (score 2):

How about if($result!=NULL)?  Or if($result!='')?  THEN send email.

Comment: nope, becuase xml always returns something even when it doesnt it counts as if it has something i cant figure this out

Comment: Why don't you echo $result and see what it returns when it's empty.

Comment: do you mind giving me the code with var_dump result inside the if statement?

Comment: instead of the if statement, try var_dump($result).  It should show exactly what the type and value of the $result variable is; it could give you an answer as what to check for.

Answer (score 2):

Test if it's truthy:

```
if($result){
   // Send mail
}
```

It will be falsey (but not false) if it's the empty string.

```
if($result === false){
   echo "Error performing request";
}else if($result){
   // Send mail because result is falsy, but not false
}
```

Comment: can i only use if($result){
   // Send mail
} without stating else if?

Comment: sebas Yes :) The `else` isn't necessary.

Comment: this is not working, tried both solution u propose but none works, the email is sent when the xml returns something and when it doesnt, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($result))
{
  // here you go
}
```

Per [PHP docs](http://php.net/empty):

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Comment: this is not working, any idea why? when i use if result only it works

Comment: @sebas - make sure you're using `!empty` as in "not empty"

Comment: im using that the returning xml is empty but is sending the email in that even though im using !empty

Answer (score 1):

what is in xml file as **!empty($result)** or **''** **false** might not work
due to the fact a xml doc will always contain something

you might want to include a error code in the xml file if not found

Comment: u are exactly right !empty doesnt work but when i simply use if result ot works..can i just use if result {} or is it risky in some way?

Comment: using just result will not work due to the fact it will always return a result.

Comment: please check the error in what i posted on this post, there is an error but for some reasons its always giving a SUCCESS

Comment: then there must be a problem with the part of script that writes success in xml file.